# App does not navigate to new page in Windows 8

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have an app that I am multi-targeting between Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 with two different projects since I am using the express editions of Visual Studio. The projects contain two XAML pages, named `MainPage` and `HelpPage`. `MainPage` contains a button on its bottom AppBar that is supposed to naviagate to `HelpPage`. In both versions, the handler for the button's click event looks like this:

```
    Private Sub btnHelp_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnHelp.Click
        If Me.Frame IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim result = Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(HelpPage)).ToString
            Debug.WriteLine(result)
        End If
    End Sub
```

In the Windows 8.1 version, this successfully navigates the app to `HelpPage` and writes `True` in the Output window.

In the Windows 8 version, this procedure remains on the same page and writes `False` in the Output window.

I have added a breakpoint to the procedure, so I know that the click handler is working correctly, but the page does nothing.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was incorrect XAML in `HelpPage`. In the juggling between Windows versions, I overlooked some copied code that didn't work in Windows 8, but did in Windows 8.1. Namely, the code was a style property of a TextBlock. I had to change my XAML from:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}">Subheader Text</TextBlock>
```

to

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SubheaderTextStyle}">Subheader Text</TextBlock>
```

For some reason, the error list did not pick this up, although the XAML editor did underline the top Style declaration in blue. Also, the app compiled fine and did not throw any exceptions when `HelpPage` was called on, but just didn't navigate to the correct page.